# Navigate to folder and run sendEmail from CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, katalon-studio, mail-sender, test-reporting

I'm building a simple email reporting system for my automated tests (in **Katalon Studio**).

When tests are failed, email gets sent using **sendEmail**.

```
    if (GlobalVariable.testSuiteStatus=='FAILED'){
      String bf = RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + '/' + 'email.bat'
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(bf)
    }
```

Email.bat contains:

```
cmd /c start cmd /k cd c:\\Program Files\\sendEmail-v156
sendEmail.exe -f sender@email.com -t receiver@email.com -s smtp.server.com:587 -xu myUsername -xp myPassword -m 'Test report text'
```

Each time this is run (or when I just doubleclick the bat file), only the first line gets executed.

So, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling cmd to open cmd again and `cd`, Which is what it does in a new window.. when you exit the new window, it will try and process `sendmail` from the working dir where you started the batch file from. Instead just try `cd /d` without the `cmd /c` or `/k` and run the executable from the batch directly:

```
@echo off
cd /d  "c:\Program Files\sendEmail-v156"
start "" /wait sendEmail.exe -f sender@email.com -t receiver@email.com -s smtp.server.com:587 -xu myUsername -xp myPassword -m 'Test report text'
```

Comment: It still doesn't send the mail. How can I pass the command after navigating to desired path? E.g. should `start "" "cmd /k cd c:\Program Files\sendEmail-v156\" "echo foo"` navigate to c:\Program Files\sendEmail-v156\ and execute the echo command?

Comment: Please forget about cmd /k. Does the command execute when you manually run `sendEmail.exe -f sender@email.com -t receiver@email.com -s smtp.server.com:587 -xu myUsername -xp myPassword -m 'Test report text'` after you `cd` to the dir?

Comment: No problems, only a pleasure.